# Is there a way to add a report template to a Google Data Studio native community connector?

Tags: looker-studio, connector

If I want to use a google data studio native community connector as my data source, for instance the Google Cloud Storage one, how can I add a report template to this data source? My problem is that I will need to create multiple reports (sharing a common template) based on the same data source.

Somewhat surprisingly, this is possible using custom community connectors but not via the Google native ones.

Comment: There aren't any 'native' Community Connector. There are native connectors provided by Google and then there are Community Connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't fully understand your requirement. I wanted to clear out the terminologies:

*Connector:* Connectors are generic pipes to any data you might have. Connectors can be native or Community Connectors. e.g. Google Sheets connector.

*Data Source:* When you provide necessary configuration and authentication to a connector and instantiate it, you create a data source. e.g. When you use the Google Sheets connector to connect to a specific Sheet that you own, a new data source is created with that Sheet's name. A single data source can be used across different reports.

*Report:* Reports are your dashboards. A report can contain multiple data sources.

*Template:* Any report that has 'copying' enabled, can be used as a template. Simply copy the report and replace the data sources attached to the original report.

Given this, I'm reiterating your requirements: you have a report that uses a data source based on the Google Cloud Storage native connector. Now you want to create multiple reports from the same report using the same data source.

The solution is to simply copy the report and make edits to the copied reports as needed.